# C++: Determining whether a variable contains no data

Tags: c++

I've been messing around in C++ a little bit but I'm still pretty new. I searched around a little bit and even using the keywords of exactly the problem I am trying to tackle yields no results. Basically I am just trying to figure out how to tell if a variable has no data. I have a file that my program reads and it searches for a specific character within that file and basically uses delimiters to determine where to store the actual data in a variable. Now I added some comments in the file saying that it should not be edited which has caused me some problems. So I pretty much want to count the number of comments, but I'm not sure how to do it because the way I had it set up was resulting in huge numbers being returned. So I figured I would attempt to fix it with a simple if statement to see if there was any data in the array while it was running the loop, and if there was then simply add +1 to my variable. Needless to say it did not work. Here's the code. And if you know a better way of doing this, by all means please do share.

```
size_t arySearchData[20];
size_t commentLines[20];
size_t foundDelimiter;
size_t foundComment;
int commentsNum;

foundDelimiter = lineText.find("]");
foundComment = lineText.find("#");

if (foundComment != std::string::npos) {
    commentLines[20] = int(foundComment);

    if (foundComment = <PROBLEM>){
        commentsNum++;
    }
}
```

So it successfully gets the two comments in my file and recognizes that they are located at the first index(0) in each line but when I tried to have it just do commentsNum++ in my first if statement it just comes up with tons of random numbers, and I am not sure why. So as I said my problem is within the second if statement, I need a void or just a better way to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And yes I do realize I could just determine if there 'was' data in the there rather than being void or null but then it would have to be specific and if the comment (#) had a space before it, then it would render my method of reading the file useless as the index will have changed.

Comment: I changed the tag to regular C++ as there does not seem to be anything CLI specific here.

Comment: All in all, your question is very unclear. I have no idea what you are actually trying to do and how your code is related to that. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: and the code is buggy too, out of bounds access + assignment in `if` make me cringe. It also looks very C-ish.

Answer (score 2):

A variable in C++ always contains data, just it may not be initialised.

```
int i;
```

It will have some value, what it is can't be determined until you do something like

```
i = 1337;
```

until you do that the value of `i` will be what ever happened to be in the memory location that `i` has been assigned to.

The compile may pick up on the fact that you are trying to use a variable which you have not actually given a value your self, but this will normally just be a warning, as their is nothing wrong as such with doing so

Comment: "the value of i will be what ever happened to be in the memory location" -> No, reading from an uninitialized local variable actually yields undefined behavior.

Comment: really? I have once or twice read an uninitialised variable like this, and just ended up with a more or less random value being used. My program did not crash, but I just ended up with 'strange' results...

Comment: Undefined behavior includes any effects that you might consider reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize commentsNum. Try this:

```
int commentsNum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `C++`  other than `static` variables, other variables are assigned undetermined values. This is primarily done to adhere to underlying philosophy -- "you don't pay for things you don't use", so it doesn't zero that memory by default." However, for `static` variables, memory is allocated at link time. Unlike runtime initialization, which would need to happen in local variables, link time allocation and initialization incur low cost.

I would recommend hence setting  `int commentsNum = 0;`